# Password validator, python program

Tags: python

Write a python program that will :

Validate a password

The program will have the user input a password

Check to see if all requirements are met

At least 6 characters long
Must have at least one upper case letter
Must have at least one lower case letter
Must have at least one numeric digit
You will have a function for each validation.

After the password is checked the program will

Return if the password passed or failed the check

**So far, I've done all the validation checks needed, but I am confused about the last part.**

*"You will have a function for each validation.
After the password is checked the program will
Return if the password passed or failed the check"*

Could some verify for me if what I did is what they're asking for? Thank you.

```
print("Requirements for password is: ")
print("--------------------")
print("6 characters or more")
print("At least one upper case letter")
print("At least one lower case letter")
print("At least one numeric digit")
print("Example of a good password: pasSword12")
print("--------------------")

p = input(("Enter a password"))

upper_case = 0
lower_case = 0
number = 0

for i in p:
    if i.isupper():
        upper_case += 1
    elif i.islower():
        lower_case += 1
    elif i.isdigit():
        number += 1

if len (p) <= 6:
    print("This is a weak password")
elif (upper_case > 0 and lower_case > 0 and number > 0):
    print("Good")
else:
    print("Too Weak")
```

Comment: It sounds like the intent is for you to write functions called (for example) `has_uppercase`, `has_lowercase`, `has_digit`, etc..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if its not an exercise (then follow ryan's answer), then youv'e done everything right!

> You will have a function for each validation

- i.isupper()
- i.islower()
- i.isdigit()

Looks like 3 functions too me :)

Comment: I think they have to _write_ a function for each validation.

Comment: I agree but only if its an exercise

Comment: And you don't think this is an exercise/assignment?